# Rango del eje Y2

Tags: gnuplot

Tengo un archivo de texto de  de tres columna "ABC.txt" y mediante gnuplot grafiqué  las columnas 2 y 3 respecto a la primera. Quisiera saber como cambio el rango del eje y2 para el gráfico de la columna 2 respecto a la 1. He tecleado los siguientes comandos :
`plot "ABC.txt" using 1:2 with lines, "ABC.txt" using 1:3 with lines.`

Deseo hacer esto debido a que el gráfico  1:2 no se visualiza con la misma escala, y quisiera que el eje y2 se encuentre entre -0.006 y -0.004.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias